# Изменение оформления тегов HTML

Tags: html

Скорее всего кто-нибудь скажет, что это полный маразм, но мне все же очень интересно :) Можно ли заставить воспринимать браузер HTML теги не в стандартном виде: `<tag></tag>`, а, например, в таком `[tag][/tag]`.

Comment: Ещё можно и свой браузер написать, он будет вообще как ты захочешь всё делать))

Comment: Можно сделать шаблонизатор и разбирать теги javascript'ом. Но, конечно, не всю страницу.

Comment: Браузер так воспринимать не будет. Это делают различные библиотеки. Как на серверной стороне, так и на строне клиента (JavaScript).

Comment: Ну я намекал на что-нибудь типа define, но JS это уже, конечно, перебор. Нет, так нет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать выучить XML))) Но мой ответ тоже больше походит на маразм)))

Comment: Не, ну я не спорю, вопрос туповат, но вот причем тут XML и что значит его выучить? :)

Comment: Выучить - (кого), научить, обучить, надоумить, образумить, умудрить; (что), изучить, научиться чему, выдолбить, вызубрить, затвердить, усвоить, пройти, нахвататься, понабираться, проштудировать, постигнуть, освоить, овладеть, одолеть, превзойти!

Comment: что значит выучить xml? Это просто расширяемый язык разметки. Как напишите так и будет.На нем нельзя программировать, только структурировать.
Да браузер парсит хтмл как xml  на то он и xhtml

Comment: Shrek... так вот как его зовут! Это сродни тому, как узнать имя Доктора :) А что такое XML я в курсе. Я просто плохо понимаю, что значит его выучить.

Comment: Я бы сказал коротко да не получится, но попробую.


ЗАЧЕМ ты тогда принял ответ если ты не знаешь, а надо оно тебе или нет?